# postgres #my table syntax error

Tags: postgresql

The following code shows syntax error near #my table seq in **postgres sql**.

```
IF (p_BusinessID = '')
    THEN
        SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SSO) SNO,Business, SSO, DisplayName, UPPER(ExServerName) ExServerName, POP, IMAP, EWS, DisplayMonth, DisplayYear 
        FROM "POP_IMAP_EWS_Data"
        WHERE DisplayYear = COALESCE(p_YearID, DisplayYear) AND MonthID = COALESCE(p_MonthID, MonthID) AND SSO = COALESCE(p_SSO, SSO);
    ELSE
       CREATE SEQUENCE #myTable_seq;

       CREATE TABLE #myTable 
       (
                     ID                                      INT DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('#myTable_seq'),
                     Item                    VARCHAR(100), 
       );

       INSERT INTO #myTable(Item)
       SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) FROM SplitString(;p_BusinessID, ',');

       SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SSO) SNO, A.BusinessID, Business, SSO, DisplayName, UPPER(ExServerName) ExServerName, POP, IMAP, EWS, DisplayMonth, DisplayYear 
       FROM "POP_IMAP_EWS_Data"A
       INNER JOIN #myTable B ON B.Item = A.BusinessID
       WHERE DisplayYear = COALESCE(p_YearID, DisplayYear) AND MonthID = COALESCE(p_MonthID, MonthID) AND SSO = COALESCE(p_SSO, SSO);
```

Can someone tell why?

Answer (score 2):

Using a `#` prefix to indicate a temporary table is specific to SQL Server (and possibly Sybase). PostgreSQL wants you to say [`create temporary table ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
create temporary table mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    item varchar(100)
);
```

Also, you'd usually just make your `id` column a `serial` column and let PostgreSQL take care of the sequence rather than hooking it all up yourself so I changed that as well; using `serial` also takes care of setting the sequence's owner.